# Looking for the most responsive and reliable basic template in the Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

I started using SFMC's "Basic" templates as well as some "Themed" templates for one of our customers. But as we started sending emails, even though we had tested the emails on a few platforms, it seems like we probably shouldn't have relied on these built-in templates.

The buttons did not look good on mobile devices and were trimmed and cut short on Outlook Windows. The double column modules were disappointedly not mobile-ready. We counted so much on drag-n-drop. Now I feel like I should build everything from scratch.

I am wondering if there is a template (be it basic or themed, etc.) which is both responsive and mobile-ready and works fine on most known platforms? You can also lead me to a best-practices page (the dos and don't) where we could have our MVP (Minimum Viable Product) concerning email. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Nope. You're better off building your own, custom templates to achieve ~90% compability / responsiveness for all the Outlook fixes etc. Consider using Litmus integration for rendering checks on less popular clients.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I either have to convince my client to buy Litmus of just go and learn how to do a bullet-proof email. It's disappointing that Salesforce sells Marketing Cloud with templates that are in no way ready for the marketing world.